# How to go to next page when web crawling using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, urllib2

I trying to do web crawling using python. But I can't figure out how to change pages automatically. 
So I found the pattern but I don't know how to go to next page automatically until it reaches end of page.

so the pattern is

'http//.../sortBy=helpful&pageNumber=0'

'http//.../sortBy=helpful&pageNumber=1'

'http//.../sortBy=helpful&pageNumber=2'

'http//.../sortBy=helpful&pageNumber=3'
and so on ...

```
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin

    def review_next_page(page=1):
           list_url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Quest-Nutrition-Protein-Apple-2-12oz/product-reviews/B00U3RGAMW/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_paging_btm_2?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1&sortBy=recent&pageNumber={0}'.format(page)
           list_url = [urljoin(list_url, review_link) for review_link in ???]
           return list_url
```

I am trying to change last number increases by 1 until it reaches the end...
Should I use for loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A `while` loop would probably be better for your needs, then you can specify how the loop breaks and keep the `pageNumber` out of the loop (so to speak)

Comment: You could use generators along with a `while` loop if you like

Comment: if I use while loop how can i avoid infinite looping?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering the question, but this is something that can be easily and conveniently handled by [`Scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/)'s [`CrawlSpider` class](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) and the [link extractors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html). You can configure what patterns should `href` match for the link to be followed. In your case, it would be something like:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'sortBy=helpful&pageNumber=\d+$'), callback=self.parse_page)
```

Comment: can you be more specific??